# Gnome Keyring - Open in while loggin in with password

Tags: gnome, login, password, keyrings

I manually created a keyring in Gnome Seahorse. I type password (not fingerprint) to login to Ubuntu 23.04. How can I unlock the keyring at login? I can'f find any settings in the options of the keyring.

Do I need to create a systemd unit service?